# How to install rosserial_arduino on 12.04 Precise?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run commands clone rosserial from the kforge repository. But later it turn out to this error

> rosmake rosserial_arduino

Why is this happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128141/how-to-install-rosserial_arduino-on-12.04-precise?/) by [Ross Marry](https://answers.ros.org/users/8466/ross-marry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of ros are you using? For Groovy+, use the github repo https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial with catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2